# Magento URl Handling?

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I have created the new magneto site and importing the data from the old site but I have the problem with the URLs. 
Old site URL starts from wwww.sitename.com
but in my new site it starts from sitename.com without www.
Now I am trying to add WWW in my magento site or remove the WWW from the old site through .htaccess file

but the problem is when I change the magento site bse URL to www.sitename.com it is giving server not found error

I have also used the htacess rule to remove the WWW from the old links?

any hint regarding this issue ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

1 ) System > Configuration > Web > Unsecure and Secure 
Check correct url are setup or not. (www)

2) .htaccess changes :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursitename.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursitename.com$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: i have added the www in the System > Configuration > Web > Unsecure and Secure but the site is not accessible , giving the server not found error

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database, the table you could edit is **core_config_data** and the values you need to change are in the path column. Change the **web/unsecure/base_url** and **web/secure/base_url** to match the new domain name by altering the value column for both records

Comment: when i change the url and add www before url it is giving server not found error

Comment: Couple things when changing this field, you must append a forward slash to the end (/), not doing this could give a server not found error. Also as Trong Nguyen Duy touched on above: there could be full URLs mentioned in the .htaccess file. Other than this, are there any other places you may have used full URL paths?

Comment: Perhaps there are some unwanted redirects under Catalog > URL Rewrites?

Comment: no the extension pages URLs are not present in that list